# From server how to call an Android app without any request?

Tags: android

In my app I have functionality like server-side some updates is done. When every updates is happen in server-side I need send those data to app without using push notifications.

Take example of Ola Cabs. Whenever user open the app it will show all cabs  information nearby user. At the same time it will send data to the  cab drivers telling that a customer needs cab like that. How to implement this functionality with out push notifications?

By using this things we can do that

1) push notifications

2) explicitly calling the server from client with given time (its bad process)

Is there any solution other than these things?

Comment: The whole tutorial is available on Google developers. Just go there
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: Push Notifications means GCM only right, other than GCM i need some other mechanism. That i am mention in my question already.

Comment: yeah push notifications

Comment: my manager need other than push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

How could client get response without request? Please read [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and [TCP/IP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). Because server cannot send response without request. So client have to initialize request first and wait for response from server. 
If you want to do same thing without GCM then i will suggest you to use socket programming. In that you can be open client port continuously to receive messages (response) without any request initiated by client.

But again, continuously opening socket port, drains device batteries, and this is bad process. In case of GCM it only open port for while when client send request to server and close after response. So I suggest you to use GCM but still you have problem with GCM then use socket programming like chat applications (e.g WhatsApp)